# /dev/xvda1 is 100% full, I increased the volume to 16GB but it's not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, rds

I'm new to Amazon AWS and I've been tasked to move a company's web app (LAMP) to amazon aws. I setup an EC2 and an RDS. I successfully setup apache, mysql and phpmyadmin. I ran into problems when I started to transfer their web app over to our EC2. The eror message "disk space full" So in the console I resized the volume from 8GB to 16GB. But the root mount is still set to 8GB..

Comment: Those commands are what you need: 
lsblk;
sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1;
sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1;
df -h;

Answer (score 4):

You need to [extend the Linux volume size](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html#recognize-expanded-volume-linux). Basically, the disk is bigger, but you need to tell Linux to use the disk.

I know SF likes steps copied in, just in case the source disappears. AWS documentation is reliable regularly updated, so in this case I won't copy the steps in.